# how are var's passed in a p:datatable in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I know that I could find this by going to the source code but I am not sure where to start.

I have a primefaces datatable (and I know it's probably the same for a simple datatable) and I am wondering how a row in the table is passed to a backing bean. That is:

```
<p:datatable value="#{viewBean.table}" var="row">
      <p:column>#{viewBean.combineValuesInRow(row)}</p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

My question is what is row? Is row a serialized pojo or is it a reference to it? And is the code above better, worse or no different than this:

```
<p:datatable value="#{viewBean.table}" var="row" rowKey="idx">
      <p:column>#{viewBean.combineValuesInRow(idx)}</p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

and then the bean just looks it up in table to get the instance?

As I write this, I'm beginning to realize that this is a stupid question (or at least asking it is stupid) but having an answer posted here would be a good thing. What I am trying to do is figure out best practice. Like, is it better to refer to a session bean directly from a xhtml page or is it better to inject the session bean into the backing view bean then have the xhtml page refer only to the view bean? I know that both ways work and there's only minimal extra effort to implement the second way. But is one better?

Comment: Whats the connection between the main question and the last paragraph? I'd say, as it all happens server side its just the same. Do what you prefer, I'd take option 1 in both cases as its easiest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My question is what is row? Is row a serialized pojo or is it a reference to it?*

Reference.

---

> *And is the code above better, worse or no different than this: [snip] and then the bean just looks it up in table to get the instance?*

Better.

---

> *Like, is it better to refer to a session bean directly from a xhtml page or is it better to inject the session bean into the backing view bean then have the xhtml page refer only to the view bean?*

Directly.